# How to pass parameter to $.keyup() ？

Tags: jquery

I want to do something like :

```
function validateBody($obj)
{

}

$ojb.keyup(validateBody($ojb));
```

How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
function validateBody(e) {
    var $obj = e.data.obj;

    // do something
}

$ojb.bind('keyup', { obj: $ojb }, validateBody);
```

Check out the documentation on [event.data](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.data) and [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind)

Comment: You do not need to use the "bind function". You can also just use the "on function". 

The function call looks like this: 
$element.on('keyup', { obj:$obj }, function(e) { validateBody(e.data.obj });

The function looks like this:
function validateBody(obj) { 
  // do something
}

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you want, correct?

```
function validateBody(obj, number) {
  //do something...
}

$ojb.keyup(function() {
  var someNumber = getNumberFromAlgorithm();
  validateBody($(this), someNumber)
});
```

Comment: No,I want to pass arbitrary parameter to it.

Comment: Where is this arbitrary parameter coming from?  Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: It's a number generated by some algorithm.

Comment: More like that?  I'm still not sure where the number is created, how it exists in the context, etc so I have to make very generalized guesses here.

Comment: Seems you don't know how to pass a parameter:(

Comment: Seems like you don't know how to word your questions.

Comment: You are asking unrelated things too much.